# How to get HTML div attribute's value from a raw HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have extracted this HTML using find().

```
<div class="merged_doc_list_sub_divs" div_type="pdf_doc" id="1500439">
Warwick University response
<img onclick="remove_doc_div(1500439)" src="/img/close.png" style="width:3%;float:right;cursor:initial;">
</div>
```

Now I want to extract id from this DIV and i tried using .attr('id') but it's giving me an error saying attr() is not a valid function, because the HTML is raw html stored in a variable.

This is what I tried

```
var destination_list = $('#merged_document_div').find('div.merged_doc_list_sub_divs');
if (destination_list.length > 0)
{
    for (index in destination_list)
    {
        if (rowData['doc_id'] == destination_list.attr('id'))
        {
            rowData["row_exist"] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So please let me know how do I do this?

Comment: show how you tried to get the id

Comment: Show your js code

Comment: Also `<img onclick="$(this).parent().remove()"` or `<img onclick="$(this).parent().hide()"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly use selector to check whether element exists

```
var destination_list = $('#merged_document_div').find('div.merged_doc_list_sub_divs#' + rowData['doc_id']);
rowData["row_exist"] = !!destination_list.length;
```

However as its ID which will be unique just directly use ID selector

```
rowData["row_exist"] = !!$('#' + rowData['doc_id']).length;
```

---

If you are using ID to store some arbitrary data, then I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes

Comment: Given that it's an `id` which should be unique, using `find()` itself is pretty much redundant too

Comment: You are a star Satpal

Comment: You mean data-1500439 instead of id='1500439'?

Comment: @Keyur, `data-id="1500439"`, However then above solution in answer will not work

Comment: Hi @Satpal is there any way to extract this id attribute from div? like converting the html into some object and access the id using attr('id').

Comment: @Keyur, Yes, you can. `$(YourVariable).attr(id)`

Answer (score 0):

**HI Keyur,**

Instead of using for loop, use each loop -

```
$.each(destination_list, function () {
                if (this.id == rowData['doc_id']) {
                    alert("div found");
                }
            });
```